# How can I make a sprite based animation using Cocos2d JS?

Tags: cocos2d-x-js

I am learning Cocos2d JS, but I can find very few tutorials and I find the documentation very vague. I can put a simple image on a layer like this:

```
var sprite = new cc.Sprite(res.my_image_png);
sprite.setAnchorPoint(0.5, 0.5);
sprite.setPosition(cc.winSize.width / 2, cc.winSize.height / 2);
this.addChild(sprite);
```

I can also move it like this:

```
var actionTo = cc.moveTo(2.5, cc.p(100, 100).easing(cc.easeInOut(1));

sprite.runAction(
    new cc.Sequence(
        actionTo,
        new cc.CallFunc(
            function() {
                cc.log("Animation complete");
            },
            this
        )
    )
);
```

How could I improve this code to also show some sprite-based animation? I would like to exchange the sprite image every 0.25 seconds. What is the designed way to do that in Cocos2d JS?